# Accessing the world-state from Big-Bang in Racket from a preset function

Tags: scheme, racket

I am creating a small game in Racket with the big bang function and four structures. My structures are below:

```
(define-struct game_main (tank missile UFO))
(define-struct tank (x aim-x aim-y))
(define-struct missile (x y vel))
(define-struct UFO (x y))
(define a-game 
  (make-game_main 
  (make-tank 370 100 100)
  (make-missile 500 500 1)
  (make-UFO 100 100)))
```

When creating a key-event handler for the big bang function, I'm using a to move the x position of the tank left, d to move it right, like so. The big-bang function is included for reference:

```
(define (controls a-game a-key)
  (cond
    [(key=? a-key "a")
     (struct-copy game_main a-game [tank (make-tank (- (tank-x (game_main-tank a-game)) 7)
                                                    (tank-aim-x (game_main-tank a-game))
                                                    (tank-aim-y (game_main-tank a-game)))])]
    [(key=? a-key "d")
     (struct-copy game_main a-game [tank (make-tank (+ (tank-x (game_main-tank a-game)) 7)
                                                    (tank-aim-x (game_main-tank a-game))
                                                    (tank-aim-y (game_main-tank a-game)))])]
    )
  )

(big-bang a-game (to-draw game_init) (on-key controls))
```

This works great; however, it's verbose. I'd like to define a function, like "move-tank-left" that simply contains the world-state changers, but defined outside the event handler. But, instead of directly editing the struct being manipulated by big-bang, it goes back to my globally set a-game game_main struct and restores the x values it began with. **How can one reference the current big-bang function world state so that you can establish functions outside of the big-bang function that will edit the temporary state?**

Here's the function in question:

```
(define move-tank-left
(make-tank
(- (tank-x (game_main-tank a-game)) 5)
(tank-aim-x (game_main-tank a-game))
(tank-aim-y (game_main-tank a-game))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference the current "big-bang" state as it doesn't exist outside of `big-bang`.
(Even `big-bang` doesn't really edit the current state –

```
(struct-copy game_main a-game ...
```

doesn't modify the `a-game` parameter, but creates a new state.)

You could pass along the entire game state from the `controls` function:

```
(define (controls a-game a-key)
  (cond
    [(key=? a-key "a")
     (struct-copy game_main a-game [tank (move-tank-left a-game)])]
    ... 

(define (move-tank-left game-state)
    (make-tank
       (- (tank-x (game_main-tank game-state)) 5)
       (tank-aim-x (game_main-tank game-state))
       (tank-aim-y (game_main-tank game-state))))
```

but passing around just the tank creates fewer dependencies and lets you add tanks easier:

```
(define (controls a-game a-key)
  (cond
    [(key=? a-key "a")
     (struct-copy game_main 
                  a-game 
                 [tank (move-tank-left (game_main-tank a-game))])]
    ...

(define (move-tank-left tank)
    (make-tank
       (- (tank-x tank) 5)
       (tank-aim-x tank)
       (tank-aim-y tank)))
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much. I see what my problem was. When creating the move-tank-left function, I didn't make it so that it accepted an argument (a tank). Instead, I hard referenced the game_main tank.